# How to debug unexported functions from required packages?

Tags: r, debugging, namespaces

A function, in a package I am using is giving me not so informative errors. I don't know what is going on. This function is called internally by the function I call. Something like this:

```
myres <- the.func(x)

the.func <-function(x){
    unexported.func(x)
}
```

How do I debug `unexported.func` ? 
Using `debug` doesn't work:

```
>debug(unexported.func)
Error in debug(undexported.func) : object 'unexported.func' not found
```

**Update:**
Currently I do nested debug like the following. But I find it inconvenient:

```
>debug(the.func) # Initiate debugging for the outer function, so I get unexported.func loaded.
>myres <- the.func(x)
Browse[2]>debug(unexported.func) # Now I can call debug with this.
```

Comment: Is the a debugger with breakpoints that can be attached?

Comment: That is a good point. `ESS` provides a way to set breakpoints. But I don't know how to navigate to the class that contains the implementation of `unexported.func` and set the breakpoint there.

Comment: This isn't anything specific to Emacs or ESS; it is really about referring to an unexported function at the R level, which is what `:::` is for.

Answer (score 9):

You can access an unexported function via the `:::` (triple-colon) operator, prefacing it with the package namespace name (i.e. the package name).

Assuming the **pkgA** contains the unexported function `unexported.func()`, we would set the debugging flag on `unexported.func()` using:

```
debug(pkgA:::unexported.func)
```

If you don't know which package (hence namespace) to use for a given unexported function, you can always determine this using `getAnywhere()`.

Comment: Hah, this is much nicer than my approach. Could you also give a solution on how to set breakpoints to `unexported.func` while in `ESS`. This problem makes me miss the `F2` in `Rstudio`.

Comment: I've not used the ess-tracebug functions much so I can't help there I'm afraid. Try the ESS mailing list and report back?